# SQLAlchemy/Flask Populating a Dropdown list error

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to populate a dropdown in Flask via SQLAlchemy calling on an oracle database.
The table in the Database has one column 'VALUE' and the values make up the drop down list.
I am running into the error:
**ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack**

Any ideas on what is missing here?

```
engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@DB.name/')
connection = engine.connect()
Base= declarative_base()

GP_DD_UPDATE_FREQ = Table('GP_DD_UPDATE_FREQ', Base.metadata,
                    Column('VALUE', String(20)))

class Dropdown():
    s = select([GP_DD_UPDATE_FREQ.c.VALUE])
    result = connection.execute(s)
    ape = [row for row in result ]

updatef = Updatefreq.ape

class ReusableForm(Form):  
    updates = SelectField('Update:', coerce=int, choices = updatef)

@app.route("/editor", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    form = ReusableForm(request.form)  # calls on form

    if request.method == 'POST':
        updates = request.form['updates']
```

**hello.html**

```
<label for="updates">Update Frequency {{ form.updates}}</label>
```

Also the list of values populates just fine if I `print updatef`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this error is caused by your mis-handle of SQLAlchemy query result. In class `Dropdown`

```
class Dropdown():
    s = select([GP_DD_UPDATE_FREQ.c.VALUE])
    result = connection.execute(s)
    ape = [row for row in result ]
```

`result` is the execution of a SQLALchemy query. And it is a [ResultProxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy) object. This `ResultProxy` object is iterable and each element when iterating is a **tuple**. Even though your `SELECT` query is to fetch only one column of the table,  each returned row is represented as `tuple` instead of `scalar`!

For example, suppose that your table column `VALUE` is like this:

```
VALUE
-------
1
2
3
```

The returned result of your query is represented like:

```
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
```

You may notice that [ResultProxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy) class provide a lot of operation functions, like

```
fetchall(), return [(1,), (2,), (3,)], a list of tuple
fetchone(), return (1,), a tuple (first time call)
fetchmany(2), return [(1,), (2,)], a list of tuple
first(), return (1,), a tuple
scalar(), return 1, a scalar
```

In your application, you want a list of scalar, instead of

```
ape = [row for row in result]
```

you should use

```
ape = [row[0] for row in result]
```

Or

```
ape = [first_of_row for first_of_row, in result]
```

Hope this illustration could answer.
Thanks!

Comment: This is definitely along the right lines as I was able to display a tuple earlier without issue.  I tried your last two suggestions and am now getting the error:
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: What's the value of `updatef = Updatefreq.ape`, could you please print out for me.

Comment: Sure, it is 

['continual', 'daily', 'weekly', 'fortnightly', 'monthly', 'quarterly', 'biannually', 'annually', 'asNeeded', 'irregular', 'notPlanned', 'unknown']

Comment: OK according to WTForms documentation the list must be setup like:
[('continual', 'continual'), ('daily', 'daily'), ('weekly', 'weekly')] with a label and a value

Comment: Yes, correct. After modification, do you get what you expect?

Comment: I simply created a "LABEL" field and duplicated my "VALUE" field in the Oracle DB.  This fixed the issue.

Comment: @rojeeer and Infinity8 could you pls kindly take a look at my query ? Thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428473/dropdown-menu-using-flask-boostrap-and-sqlite